# babel-node gives import error when only when writing to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

The purpose of this whole exercise is to run ES2015 javascript in the browser. I have a test setup like this:

foo.js:

```
export class Foo {}
```

main.js:

```
import {Foo} from './foo';
console.log('ready')
```

Finally I have also a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

This code runs fine

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node main.js
ready
```

The first step (and please correct me if I'm wrong) is to transpile this from ES2015 to ES5

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node main.js -o main-es5.js
/Users/dev/test/main.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {Foo} from './foo'; 
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Just for completeness, my last step would be

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/browserify main-es5.js bundle.js
```

Any help why on this matter would be appreciated

Comment: If you're using Browserify, you'd want https://github.com/babel/babelify

Comment: thnx, babelify is what I need, thnx!

Answer (score 2):

`babel-node` is just an interactive repl which precompiles input source.

To compile es6 and emit es5, do this:

`babel main.js > main-es5.js`

Incidentally, you would also need to `export` the class in **foo.js** to make it available in `main.js`. In your example, `Foo` is undefined.